# Multiple Repos for Linux laptops

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, localrepository

I'm working on a project to better manage updates on our Linux (Ubuntu) laptops. Currently we already have a working solution for desktops.

For our desktops, they're configured to point to a local repository on our network for updates and new packages. This is fine since they never leave our internal network.

However, with our laptops we're exploring the idea of configuring both our local repo and the standard Ubuntu repos. The idea being that users would be able to install software and updates from our local repo while onsite, and use the standard Ubuntu (internet) repos while at home.

In practice, I've tested this by adding 2 sources to the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory: 00-local-repo.list and 50-ubuntu-default.list
Since both repos would contain the same packages (and versions of those packages), apt should prefer the local repo if I understand correctly (assuming apt searches the sources directory in alphanumeric order).

The problem is, when the device has no connection to our network, it doesn't fallback to using the internet repos. It just throws up an error:

```
$ sudo apt install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 libllvm10
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  ctags vim-doc vim-scripts
The following NEW packages will be installed
  vim
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 1,238 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,111 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://local-repo.example.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5 [1,238 kB]
Err:1 http://local-repo.example.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:1e38f267bf4c06e424b166e8d666ffd6ce25c657012892d099651bee18a2c834
   - SHA1:796c962d044f99a81b187211e6ce9a0a44b8d5d1 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:198ccbb07a9fc8ebe67a213eab6a3e96 [weak]
   - Filesize:1237624 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:970310343d0d5b0f40363e17367cbd8a3dbeb809149b31850bc790f1df307b13
   - SHA1:38aca684355969d0e9d826831459568296560757 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:63c787e1b487e72a7aee2a4ac9c86f9e [weak]
   - Filesize:1032 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Fri, 21 May 2021 12:43:28 +0000
Fetched 1,032 B in 0s (8,474 B/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://local-repo.example.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim_8.1.2269-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:1e38f267bf4c06e424b166e8d666ffd6ce25c657012892d099651bee18a2c834
    - SHA1:796c962d044f99a81b187211e6ce9a0a44b8d5d1 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:198ccbb07a9fc8ebe67a213eab6a3e96 [weak]
    - Filesize:1237624 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:970310343d0d5b0f40363e17367cbd8a3dbeb809149b31850bc790f1df307b13
    - SHA1:38aca684355969d0e9d826831459568296560757 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:63c787e1b487e72a7aee2a4ac9c86f9e [weak]
    - Filesize:1032 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Fri, 21 May 2021 12:43:28 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

My question is, is it possible to configure both repos and have apt install packages from each depending on which is currently available?

Comment: This is an interesting question. To the best of my knowledge, you cannot have `apt` exclude certain repositories based on the network a machine is connected to. Will bookmark this one with the hope that someone knows if this is doable 

Comment: Hmmm. Starting in 21.04, apt implemented Phased Updates. So the two repos may not be identical. Are you open to having the laptops VPN to your repo? That would be easier than kludging the sources.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for the input. Currently we're using Ubuntu 20.04 for our laptops.
Regarding the VPN, it could be a solution but in our case we're attempting to avoid unnecessary traffic through our VPN appliance. Though maybe that will change in future.

Currently, we encourage users not to connect to our VPN unless they need access to internal resources to ensure there's sufficient bandwidth for all who need it. We recently upgraded our VPN but it can still be overwhelmed when many users are connected.

Comment: There is no built-in apt method for selecting sources based on criteria. It's not a use case the apt developers considered. It's possible to set source priorities, but that seems a poor fit for your use case: Remote users will get spammed by 404 Errors even when everything is working properly.

Comment: However, it is quite possible to script network-detection logic (I do it for laptop backups). Then your laptops can swap the sources.list file to reflect their appropriate network. It's an ugly kludge, and it might break release-upgrades (which expect a static sources.list). You can use similar logic to engage a VPN instead (the VPN tunnel need exist only during the update/upgrade -- not always-on).

Comment: @user535733 thanks again. Some sort of network-detection logic might work well. This would be easy enough to test at least. I'll give that a go and see how effective it is.